# Loading WMS layer into QGIS Project through Python standalone script

Tags: pyqgis, wms, google, standalone, layout-manager

I can load WMS layers by coding on QGIS Python console, those are the codelines:

```py
# Google Satelite URL wms 
url = 'type=xyz&url=http%3A//mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs%3Dy%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D'
# Constructing layer thoughout wms url
layer = QgsRasterLayer(url, 'Google Satelite', 'wms')
# Add this layer to the current project
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

I use QGIS 3.16 in a Ubuntu Linux VM. When I type these line of code on QGIS console this is what I get:

[image]

The problem occur when I try execute the same lines in a standalone script (using PyCharm IDE) and after load WMS layer I save a copy of this project, those are the lines i run in PyCharm standalone script:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject
import requests

# QGIS instalation folder path
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr/qgis', True)

# QGIS reference
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

# Initiating QGIS
qgs.initQgis()

# Creating a variable to my qgis project
project = QgsProject.instance()

# Read a specific project
### DOWNLOAD https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pqk5W3y47Mt4rjlN1QzGoarBGGl6B3og/view?usp=sharing
project.read('path/to/qgisproject/with/0001_tester/layout/0001.qgz')

# google satelite image WMS url
# class googleWMS:
url = "http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
uri = "type=xyz&url="+requests.utils.quote(url)

# Create a layer from WMS url
tms_layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri, "Google Satelite", 'wms')

# Add this layer into project
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(tms_layer)

# Save the project in another location
QgsProject.instance().write('path/to/qgisproject.qgz')
```

The script can load the layer into qgis project and save the file, but the WMS layer is broken... No image is loaded to workspace.

[image]

Comment: Not able to reproduce. I run your code in a Python script I execute in PyQGIS Python console. Then, in recent project, I click on the newly created project ant it works.

Comment: Yes, on qgis python console those lines work just fine... My issue is when i try use a standalone script, in pycharm

Comment: Sorry but your screenshot was misleading me

Comment: I really sorry, it is because i did run the same lines in a standalone script, using pycharm IDE, and in this case i have the right side of my screenshoot as result. I am gonna edit this question in order to make it more clear.

Comment: what is the result if you print that line (in your script standalone)?

`tms_layer.isValid()`

if is False the url params is bad or the wms provider dont load corrrect

after you load the providers in this line:
`qgs.initQgis()`

you need to print the providers with:

`print(QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList())`

Check if the wms provider is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you run `QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()` in the PyCharm version, you will be able to notice that the provider wms is not loaded. This happens because the specified path is not correct and the Standalone version running under PyCharm does not have access to wms.

To fix this, just run in QGIS Python Console:

```
QgsApplication.showSettings()
```

Then an associated path called `QGIS_PREFIX_PATH` will appear.
Finally, just replace in the PyCharm code the `qgis_prefix` for the path indicated above.

```
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgis_prefix = "YOUR PATH"
qgs.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True)
qgs.initQgis()
```